# React not re-rendering after redux update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
import {UPDATE_USER} from '../actions/index';
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
createdAt:"",
name:"",
email:"",
password:"",
skill:"",
goal:"",
step1:"",
step2:"",
step3:"",
step4:"",
step5:"",
posts:[],
completed:0

}


export default function(state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) {
  if (action.error) {
    action.type = 'HANDLE_ERROR'; // change the type
  }
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_USER:

    console.log(action.payload)

return {
createdAt:action.payload.createdAt,
name:action.payload.name,
email:action.payload.email,
password:action.payload.password,
goal:action.payload.goal,
skill:action.payload.skill,
step1:action.payload.step1,
step2:action.payload.step2,
step3:action.payload.step3,
step4:action.payload.step4,
step5:action.payload.step5,
completed:action.payload.completed,

}
```

React is not detecting a prop change. I'm pretty sure the answer lies with me mutating reducer arguments(from researching the question). Does anyone know how I would restructure to not mutate?

edit -my react class snippet  is below. My map dispatch to props is at bottom. A user logs in to app gets redirected to this page where I set local state of page from redux in componentwillMount(). Then I have a function that calls api and updates redux. React is supposed to see this change because props have changed? Or do I have to set state manually within a componentWillRecieveProps()?

```
    class YourPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {

      post:"",
      date:"",
      email:"",
      completed:0,
      posted:true,
      timeSincePost:"",
      lastPost:""


    }
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
}



const mapStateToProps = (state) =>({


name:state.user.name,
email:state.user.email,
completed:state.user.completed,

})



const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  callApi: (value, state) => {

var obj = {
date:moment.tz(moment.tz.guess()).format(),
post:state.post,
email:state.email,
completed:(parseFloat(state.completed) + .75),
}

    API.addPost(obj)
    .then(function(res){
      dispatch(updateUser(res.data))
    })
  }

})
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(YourPage);
```

Comment: This is just your reducer, which looks fine (missing a close bracket (typo), could be smaller code, no biggie).  What does your component that's not re-rendering look like?   Is it attached to the state using mapStateToProps?

Comment: Hello @billjamesdev yeah it is hooked up to mapStateToProps.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not seeing anything "wrong".   Your page should re-render when name/email/completed parts of state change, assuming that they do.   About the only thing I'd try is just putting user directly in your props via mapStateToProps, rather than digging in and pulling just those 3 sub-props.

Answer (score 0):

Use Object.assign

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

```
import { UPDATE_USER } from '../actions/index';
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
  createdAt: "",
  name: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  skill: "",
  goal: "",
  step1: "",
  step2: "",
  step3: "",
  step4: "",
  step5: "",
  posts: [],
  completed: 0
}


export default function (state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) {
  if (action.error) {
    action.type = 'HANDLE_ERROR'; // change the type
  }
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_USER:

      console.log(action.payload)

      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        createdAt: action.payload.createdAt,
        name: action.payload.name,
        email: action.payload.email,
        password: action.payload.password,
        goal: action.payload.goal,
        skill: action.payload.skill,
        step1: action.payload.step1,
        step2: action.payload.step2,
        step3: action.payload.step3,
        step4: action.payload.step4,
        step5: action.payload.step5,
        completed: action.payload.completed,

      });
```

Comment: That's effectively the same as what the OP is doing.  Their "return { alltheblah }" also creates a new object.   They could also use return { ...action.payload }, if using ES6.

Comment: Actually yes, I didn't see he is returning whole object.  anyways for further analysis more code would be helpful